# Reproducing "Gallery of processor cache effects"

Tags: c, macos, caching, hardware

Having read [this](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) article I tried to reproduce the example on my Mac. However my curve for the first example looks completely different and I don't understand why..

[image: Updating every k-th int]

My code is below:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mach_absolute_difference(uint64_t end, uint64_t start, struct timespec *tp) {
    uint64_t difference = end - start;
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t info = {0,0};

    if (info.denom == 0)
        mach_timebase_info(&info);

    uint64_t elapsednano = difference * (info.numer / info.denom);

    tp->tv_sec = elapsednano * 1e-9;
    tp->tv_nsec = elapsednano - (tp->tv_sec * 1e9);
}

int main(void)
{
    int len = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*len);

    uint64_t start,end;
    struct timespec tp;

    start = mach_absolute_time();
    for (int i = 0; i <len; i += K) 
        arr[i] = 0;
    end = mach_absolute_time();

    mach_absolute_difference(end, start, &tp);

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("simple_array.log", "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%i\t%ld\t%ld\n", K, tp.tv_sec,
            tp.tv_nsec);
    fclose(fp);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I measured the time as described in [this blog](http://www.wand.net.nz/~smr26/wordpress/2009/01/19/monotonic-time-in-mac-os-x/), hoping that it's correct. I'm also wondering what I should use to either measure execution time or CPU cycles on a Mac. Or even nicer it would be see the amount of cache hit/misses for a certain function. Shark however only shows l2 cache misses in percentages.

Update this is it when compiled for 32 bit, note that the int size changes from 8 bytes to 4 bytes

[image: Updating every k-th int compiled for 32bit]

Comment: Would be much easier if you experimented with this in assembler. This is why using C instead of an assembler for learning low level concepts is bad.

Comment: I never used x86 assembler and I currently don't have the time to learn it. However in "Gallery of processor cache effects" C# is used, which even more high level..

Comment: I've had the same issues reproducing his results, even with the `-O0` flag enabled...

Comment: Where did you set the value for K?

Comment: Probably forgot it when copy / pasting the code. I don't remember the question is 10 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Your work loop has no observable side effects; are you sure the compiler isn't optimising some or all of it away?
- An `int` is probably not one byte in size
- The bigger you make `K`, the less overall work you're doing (`i` reaches `len` in fewer iterations)

Comment: How can I ensure that the compiler does not optimize it away? I compiled with -O0 (using gcc).. Sure int is 8 bytes in a 64bit arch, I guess

Comment: It probably makes more sense when dividing it by 8.

Comment: Ok the curve (32bit) is flatter after 16.. maybe there is also too much noise on my sys..

Comment: @Nils: On `-O0` the compiler probably isn't optimising the loop away (although you could check the disassembly to be sure).  However, the surest way is to subsequently do something with `arr[]`, like write it to a file.